# Nameserver validation

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation

The code below kinda works except `yes.com` is shown as `valid` while I need to accept only this format `ns1.yes.com`, `www.yes.com`, accepting numbers and no dash or dot at the front or at the end of nameserver. Help me please.

```
 <html>
 <head>
<title>Validate name server</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function validSubdomain() {
        var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$/;
        var val = document.getElementById("nameserver").value;

    if(val == ''){
         alert("Please enter the name server"); 
         return false; 
    } 
        if(re.test(val)) { 
            alert("valid format");
        }

        if(!re.test(val)) {
            alert("invalid format");
        }

    }
    </script>        
     </head>

     <body>
     Insert nameserver :  <input name="txt_domain" id="nameserver" type="text" size="30" /> <input name="btn_validate" type="button" value="Validate" onclick="validSubdomain()" />
     </body>
    </html>
```

Demo page: http://khamis.cheapantivirus.me/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the value by dots and count the resulting parts.

```
var parts = val.split('.');
if (parts.length < 3) { alert('invalid') }
```

Comment: You're not doing any validation on the parts of the host. For example, that would match "@.@.@" It would also match if there were more than 3.

Comment: He already has the validation in place. I wasn't sure if he wanted exactly 3 or at least 3.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a bit more explicit on the pattern you need to match. I'm assuming you want 3 alphanumeric "words" separated by two dots.

This regex will match what you want:

```
var re = /[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+){2}/
```

If you wanted to match *at least* 3 parts in the host, e.g. "foo.bar.example.com" or "www.example.co.uk", just modify the quantifier at the end to be open-ended:

```
var re = /[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+){2,}/
```

Comment: My apologies for not making my question clear. Sorry for wasting your time. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems you forget about the possibilities of double (or more) dashes.
Now I know there are ccTLD's accepting multiple dashes in a row, but usually that's "forbidden".